# add (List<? extends Z>) where Z is an interface . Class B extends A implements Z why cant we call add() with a List<A>

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, bounded-wildcard

```
 Interface Z{}
```

Consider a simple interface Z as declared above.

```
Class A{}
```

A simple class A as declared above.

```
 Class B extends A implements Z{}
```

Class B extends class A and implements interface Z

```
class Test{

static void add(List<? super Z>){}

public static void main(String[]  args){
List<A> aaa= new ArrayList<>();
add(aaa);  //Gives error here
} 
}
```

The add method in above test class has a parameter List so as far as i know i can call it with alist of type Z or with a list of type  **super class of implementation class of Z.**

class B is an implementation of Z but is also a child of A so class A satisfies the condition above .It is a super class of (class B) implementation class of Z(class B).

So when i call add() with an   ArrayList why does it give an error.

Comment: Because it is `B` that implements `Z`, not `A`. Since your test code doesn't use `B` at all, forget that `B` exists, then try to explain to yourself why the code should work. You can't.

Comment: `List<? super Z>` is a list to which it's safe to add a `Z`. But `aaa` is a `List<A>`, to which anything you add has to be specifically an `A` (or a subclass, or literal null).

Comment: @AndyTurner if i create add(List<?  super Runnable>) i can call it with List<Object>.where Object is parent of Thread and Thread extends Object implements Runnable

Comment: @RudhraKoul yes, that's because you can add a `Runnable` to a `List<Object>`. Your question is describing, by this example, `add(List<? super Object>)` and calling it with `List<Runnable>`.

Comment: `add(List<? extends Z>)` should work. But that's not what your code says.

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks for the explanation.I got the point.Just one more question if i have a method add(List<? super Z>) where Zis an interface what kind of lists can i use to call this method with?.I know I can call it with List<Z>,.List<Object> or a List<Parent Interface of Z>.Is there something else this method can be called with?

Comment: `List<Z>`, `List<? super Z>`, `List<Object>` or `List<? super Object>` (clearly there is no supertype of `Object`, but `List<? super Object>` is a valid type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine this is the method body of `add`. This compiles fine:

```
static void add(List<? super Z> list){
  list.add(new Z() {});  // Fine.
}
```

Also, this compiles fine.

```
List<A> aaa= new ArrayList<>();
// ... Something.
A a = aaa.get(0);
```

Now, what if the `... Something` is:

```
add(aaa);  // Compiler error!
```

What would happen if that compiler error didn't happen? A `ClassCastException` on the `A a = aaa.get(0);` line, because it's an instance of some subclass of `Z` that's not `A`.

Try it, by invoking `add((List) aaa)`.

This is why the compiler stops you doing it. `List<? super Z>` is a list to which it's safe to add instances of `Z`, or any subclass. `List<A>` is a list to which it's safe to add instances of `A`, or any subclass, or null; and anything you retrieve from the list will be an `A`, a subclass, or null. Some instances of `Z` aren't instances of `A`.

Comment: Thanks..I got the answer.Nice explanation.